# Why am I getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise

Here is my initial code I wrote to console log the data I want

```js
const fetchPokemon2 = () =>
  {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 151; i++) 
    {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then( res => res.json())
      .then( data => 
        {
        console.log(data);
        const pokemon = {}

        if (data.types['1'])
          {
          pokemon['name']   = data.name;
          pokemon['id']     = data.id;
          pokemon['sprite'] = data.sprites['front_default'];
          pokemon['type1']  = data.types["0"].type.name;
          pokemon['type2']  = data.types["1"].type.name;   
          } 
        else 
          {
          pokemon['name']   = data.name;
          pokemon['id']     = data.id;
          pokemon['sprite'] = data.sprites['front_default'];
          pokemon['type1']  = data.types["0"].type.name;
          }
        console.log(pokemon);
        })
    }
  }
fetchPokemon2();
```

It worked fine but this isnt the recommended way so I'm trying to do this

```js
const fetchPokemon = () =>
  {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 151 ; i++) 
    {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`
    promises.push(fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()));
    };
  Promise.all(promises).then( results => 
    {
    const pokemon = results.map(data => 
      ( { name   : data.name
        , id     : data.id
        , sprite : data.sprites["front_default"]
        , type   : data.types["0"].type.name
        , type2  : data.types["1"].type.name
        }
      ));
    console.log(pokemon);
    });
  };
fetchPokemon()
```

However this line of code

> type2: data.types["1"].type.name
> is giving the error **Uncaught (in promise)
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined**

which is confusing me a lot because this **type: data.types["0"].type.name** is perfectly fine could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: _“`data.types["0"].type.name` is perfectly fine”_ — So what? `data.types["0"]` exists, `data.types["1"]` does not. You’re never checking if either of them exist.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is no value for the specified array or object index. That means `data.types[1]` is probably undefined, hence the error **Cannot read property 'type' of undefined** for `data.types[1].type...`

In the second code sample, you aren't checking if `data.types[1]` exists.  You can always access the value safely by doing:

```
...
type2: data.types[1] && data.types[1].type && data.types[1].type.name
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the API response, some of the values have only 1 element in the types array. That could be the issue. You need to check if data exists or not before assigning them.

`type2: data.types[1] && data.types[1].type && data.types[1].type.name`